# How do I restrict a report to only show current data

Tags: powerbi

I'm brand new to Power BI and I'm used to setting up most of my data in SQL Server (for SSRS).  I have a data set and I was able to add in a Calendar table with my dates.  My goal is to do a Year-over-year comparison.  I got the year-over-year part working with the help of a couple of tutorials, but I want to restrict the report output to only data up to the last end of month (otherwise the YoY shows a case differential for dates out into 2021 - not helpful).  I need a dynamic filter and all I seem to be able to set are static filters.  This filter needs to be on the data itself - nothing a user can or should touch.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want your filter to be exactly? Which date columns get what filter?

Comment: If you put together a year-over-year dataset, the yoy column starts one year after your first date and extends out one year after your data, ie. into the future.  I eventually figured it out by creating a "Future" column on the data which used an IF to test the date against today() and resulted in "Yes" if > today() and "No" if <= today().  Then I just filtered the report explicitly to only take values where "Future" = "No".